# has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'

Tags: javascript, java, angular, java-ee

Estou desenvolvendo uma Backend em Java(Rest Spring) integrado com Front em Angular 8. Ao tentar listar o a lista de usuarios(via JSON) recebo essa mensagem:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8080/contatos' from
>   origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource.

**Imagem:**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O repositório: https://github.com/alexjosesilva/desafio-java-pl-apply

Criei um arquivo config.js para configurar a proxy(front):

```
const proxy = [
  {
    context: '/api',
    target: 'http://localhost:8080'
  }
];
module.exports = proxy;
```

**Codigo do service.ts** no qual ocorre a requisição http:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class UserService {

  private baseUrl = 'http://localhost:8080/contatos';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getUser(id: number): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get(`${this.baseUrl}/${id}`);
  }
  createUser(user: Object): Observable<Object> {
    return this.http.post(`${this.baseUrl}`, user);
  }

  updateUser(id: number, value: any): Observable<Object> {
    return this.http.put(`${this.baseUrl}/${id}`, value);
  }

  deleteUser(id: number): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.delete(`${this.baseUrl}/${id}`, { responseType: 'text' });
  }

  getUserList(): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get(`${this.baseUrl}`);
  }
}
```

E criei uma classe webMVCConfigureAdapter() para habilitar os acessos ao back:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
      registry.addMapping("/**")
     .allowedOrigins("*")
     .allowedHeaders("*")
     .allowedMethods("GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE", "OPTIONS", "HEAD", "TRACE", "CONNECT");
    }
}
```

**Usei as anotações:**  @CrossOrigin  na classe ContatoResource.java afim de a 
habitar o acesso ao json.

Contudo o erro ainda persiste.

**Classe ContatoResource.java** 
package com.stefanini.contatos.resource;

```
import java.util.List;

import javax.validation.Valid;

import org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.CrossOrigin;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.DeleteMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PutMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.stefanini.contatos.model.Contato;
import com.stefanini.contatos.repository.Contatos;


@RestController
@RequestMapping("/contatos")
public class ContatosResource {


    @Autowired
    private Contatos contatos;


    @PostMapping
    public Contato adicionar(@Valid @RequestBody Contato contato) {
        return contatos.save(contato);
    }

    @CrossOrigin
    @GetMapping
    public List<Contato> listar() {
        return contatos.findAll();
    }


    @GetMapping("/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<Contato> buscar(@PathVariable Long id) {
        Contato contato = contatos.findOne(id);

        if (contato == null) {
            return ResponseEntity.notFound().build();
        }

        return ResponseEntity.ok(contato);
    }


    @PutMapping("/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<Contato> atualizar(@PathVariable Long id, 
            @Valid @RequestBody Contato contato) {
        Contato existente = contatos.findOne(id);

        if (existente == null) {
            return ResponseEntity.notFound().build();
        }

        BeanUtils.copyProperties(contato, existente, "id");

        existente = contatos.save(existente);

        return ResponseEntity.ok(existente);
    }


    @DeleteMapping("/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<Void> remover(@PathVariable Long id) {
        Contato contato = contatos.findOne(id);

        if (contato == null) {
            return ResponseEntity.notFound().build();
        }

        contatos.delete(contato);

        return ResponseEntity.noContent().build();
    }
}
```

**Pesquisas**

1. [Habilitando Cross no spring boot](http://andreybleme.com/2016-11-27/cors-spring/)
2. [Spring and Cross](https://spring.io/blog/2015/06/08/cors-support-in-spring-framework)
3. [Acesso_CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTTP/Controle_Acesso_CORS)

Comment: Não sei como resolve isso em Java, mas o CORS é um conjunto de cabeçalhos que o servidor manda para o cliente, dizendo quais sites podem acessar aquele serviço, com que métodos, etc. Assim, mesmo que um outro site queira acessar o serviço, o browser se recusa. O principal é o "Access-Control-Allow-Origin". Uma forma rápida é enviar "Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *" (asterisco) permite qualquer cliente, não é o ideal do ponto de vista da segurança mas resolve o problema imediato.

Comment: Angular é um framework do lado cliente. No node.js, se você usa o Express como servidor, pode tentar usar o módulo cors https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/cors.html

Comment: Relacionada: [Como Configurar o CORS corretamente no Spring Boot?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/262830/3774)

Comment: Relacionada: [Como liberar o CORS para determinado endereço?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/162607/3774)

Comment: Onde está o arquivo de configuração do projeto?

Comment: @emanuelcavalcante no back ou front ?

Comment: No back........

Comment: https://github.com/alexjosesilva/desafio-java-pl-apply/blob/master/backend/src/main/resources/application.properties

Comment: criei um arquivo chamado: WebConfig ele foi descrito no codigo acima @emanuelcavalcante

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Uma outra solução seria você registrar as origens, da seguinte forma:

- Dentro de `com.stefanini.contatos.config` crie uma classe `WebConfig.java`
- Insira o seguinte codigo:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry.addMapping("/**");// <- assim permite de qualquer origem, troque "/**" pelo seu dominio por exemplo "http://meudominio.com"
    }
}
```

Você também pode especificar quais verbos são permitidos, veja:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry.addMapping("/**")
                .allowedMethods("GET", "POST", "PUT");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Crie um arquivo chamado CorsFilter.java em `com.stefanini.contatos.config`

Dentro deste arquivo insira o seguinte codigo:

```
import org.springframework.core.Ordered;
import org.springframework.core.annotation.Order;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.IOException;

/**
 * @author emanuel
 *
 */
@Component
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
public class CorsFilter implements Filter {

    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain)
            throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;
        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;

        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods",
                "ACL, CANCELUPLOAD, CHECKIN, CHECKOUT, COPY, DELETE, GET, HEAD, LOCK, MKCALENDAR, MKCOL, MOVE, OPTIONS, POST, PROPFIND, PROPPATCH, PUT, REPORT, SEARCH, UNCHECKOUT, UNLOCK, UPDATE, VERSION-CONTROL");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
                "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Key, Authorization");
        if ("OPTIONS".equalsIgnoreCase(request.getMethod())) {
            response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
        } else {
            chain.doFilter(req, res);
        }
    }

    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) {
        // not needed
    }

    public void destroy() {
        // not needed
    }

}
```

Rode o projeto novamente para vê se concertou ou mudou o erro. Caso o erro persista deve ser no front-end.
 Então só inspecionando para verificar se está passando corretamente todos os headers necessários.

Answer (score 1):

pode tentar assim

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecutiryConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private static final String[] PUBLIC_MATCHERS = { "/h2-console/**", "/swagger-ui.html" };

    @Autowired
    private Environment env;


    @Bean
    CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration().applyPermitDefaultValues();
        configuration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("POST", "GET", "PUT", "DELETE", "OPTIONS"));
        final UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
        return source;
    }
}
```

Comment: Eduardo Sampaio em qual contexto devo criar essa classe ? Encontrei esse classe em outras pesquisas que realizei pela internet. Contudo como ela se relaciona com outras classe? E em qual pacote devo cria-la ?

Comment: Eduardo Sampaio vc conseguiu analisar o repositorio no github ?

Comment: na estrutura do meu projeto ficou assim olhe no gihub https://github.com/EduardoSampaio/spring-boot-gerenciador-rh/blob/master/src/main/java/com/gerenciador/rh/config/SecutiryConfig.java